# ObjectBox golang Write to file

Tags: json, file, go, save, objectbox

Is there a possible way to write my ObjectBox-Box Data to a file, after parsing it to code.

I tried to marshal it with json but it keeps giving me

```
{"ObjectBox":{}}
``
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out, that the library saves the data.
Whenever you just call a new builder, it does not refresh the database, but it calls the current one.